# Is it possible to dynamically redirect URL using htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

Is there any way to dynamically redirect URLs. For example, I want to redirect any URL from `https://example.com/NNNNN` to `https://examplecom/?p=NNNNN`.

Where `NNNNN` could be any possible numbers.

For example: `https://example.com/1796` should redirect to `https://example.com/?p=1796`.

Comment: Redirect or rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow has already an answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551553/htaccess-redirecting-dynamic-url

I guess that this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ /?p=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks realloc, i tried this but didnt work for me. I tried below code. `RewriteRule ^/(\d[^/]+) /?p=$1/ [R=302,L]`

Comment: In `.htaccess` (directory context) you need to remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. (The above directive - with a slash prefix - will never match.) This directive also needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, _before_ the WordPress front-controller (otherwise it will never get processed). If the source URL should only ever contain digits then include an end-of-string anchor `$` on the _pattern_.

Comment: @MrWhite thanks but sorry to say i not very clear i can place the code on top of .htaccess but could you please confirm the code should like after amendment. Are you saying it should be like `RewriteRule ^(\d[^/]+) ?p=$1/ [R=302,L]`

Comment: Not quite... only remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, not the _substitution_. You also _added_ a slash to the end of the _substitution_ - that's not in your initial example? For example: `RewriteRule ^(\d[^/]+) /?p=$1 [R=302,L]`. If the URL should only consist of digits then the regex should be more restrictive: `RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ /?p=$1 [R=302,L]`

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite this is working like a charm, still testing though `RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ /?p=$1 [R=302,L]`

Comment: I corrected the answer to reflect what @MrWhite wrote in the comments. Very interesting, thanks!